# NetSuite - How can I get the users and roles via SuiteTalk API?

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk, netsuite-rest-api

I am trying to find a way to use NetSuite API and pull information about the users and what role each user has.

It seems very complicated to perform such action via NetSuite REST API.

I have the client id, secret and token id and secret, it seems like I have successfully authenticated (OAuth1) but I can't find the right call to get this information.

Would appericate any help.

Thanks!

Tried finding the right call but everything I attempt fails